# Type error - Sorting columns so that each row sums up to 10

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I'm currently working on a VBA code aimed at sorting columns so that each row sums up to 10

However, I'm encountering a 'type incompatible' error in the rng.Find line. Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error?

Thanks in advance!

The column has only 2 values: minimum and maximum. The goal is to find the sum of each row. If the sum is not 10, swap the minimum or maximum value in the current column to a different cell in the same row. Then, recalculate the sum and repeat the process until the sum is 10. Finally, move on to the next column and repeat the process for all rows.

Before Code:
[image]

After Code:
[image]

```
Sub OrganizarParaSoma10()
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim row As Range
    Dim coluna As Integer
    Dim valorRestante As Integer
    Dim MinValor As Double
    Dim MaxValor As Double
    Dim TempValor As Double
    Dim TempCelula As Range
    Dim celula As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    
    ' Defina a planilha onde estão os dados
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha2")
    qtdeLinhas = Range("B5").End(xlDown).row
    ' Defina a faixa de células que deseja rearranjar (substitua "A1:J10" pela faixa correta)
    Set rng = ws.Range("Arrumar")
    
    ' Itera sobre cada linha na faixa
    For j = 5 To qtdeLinhas
        Dim soma As Integer
        soma = 0
        For i = 2 To 6
        soma = soma + Cells(j, i) + Cells(j, i + 8)
        Next i
        
        If soma <> 10 Then
            For Each col In rng.Columns
            MinValor = WorksheetFunction.Min(col)
            MaxValor = WorksheetFunction.Max(col)
            
            If col.Cells(j).Value = MinValor Then
                
                Set TempCelula = rng.Find(What:=MaxValor, After:=rng.Cells(j, col), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                
                TempValor = TempCelula.Value
                celula = col.Cells(j).Value
                col.Cells(j).Value = TempValor

                soma = 0
                For i = 2 To 6
                soma = soma + Cells(j, i) + Cells(j, i + 8)
                Next i
                
                If soma = 10 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            
            ElseIf col.Cells(j).Value = MaxValor Then
                
                Set TempCelula = rng.Find(What:=MinValor, After:=rng.Cells(j, col), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                
                TempValor = TempCelula.Value
                celula = col.Cells(j).Value
                col.Cells(j).Value = TempValor

                soma = 0
                For i = 2 To 6
                soma = soma + Cells(j, i) + Cells(j, i + 8)
                Next i
                
                If soma = 10 Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
            
            Next col
        
        End If
    Next j
    
        
       
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your post to share sample data and expected output. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sorry, i add the image before and after the code